# Массив-как поле класса в js

Tags: javascript

хочу сделать массив как поле класса.

**1)** Пытался через конструктор(передавая ему другой массив) инициализировать элементы массива:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге такая **ошибка:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2)** Не понял,почему возникла ошибка (из **п1**) и решил указать массив как поле класса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге получилась такая **ошибка:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я до этого писал на плюсах,где очень просто и легко создавать расличные private,public поля,инициализировать их в конструкторе и делать какие-то действия.
Первый раз пишу на js,опыта вообще 0(просто проект для вуза нужно сделать на js)

И вообще не понимаю,что происходит,помогите пожалуйста!

**P.S:** писал в **VsCode** ,использовал расширение **jshint** . **ES6** .

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Приложите пожалуйста весь код в виде отформатированного текста. Это удобнее копировать чтобы воспроизводить проблему

Comment: `this.array = [...initArray]` должно сработать. А так вы не объявили `this.array`, а уже обращаетесь к этому свойству.

Comment: @Leonid спасибо,тоже попробую!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что в *Js*  поля класса объявляются в конструкторе. Да, это смотрится странно, но это так. В итоге надо его вначале объявить, а потом пользоваться, если нужно

```
class Player {
    constructor(initArray) {
        this.array = []; // <--- вот это прокатит

        for (let i = 0; i < initArray.length; ++i) {
            this.array[i] = initArray[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Поэтому возникла как и первая так и вторая ошибка. Первая - потому что свойство не было объявлено в конструкторе. Вторая - потому что так писать свойства классов нельзя. Но можно в виде геттеров и сеттеров (properties must be methods)

Comment: Ох как необычно,странно что в гугле об этом мало инфы(может плохо искал).
Спасибо огромное!!!!

Comment: @Pavel Сам сейчас ищу и не нахожу :D

Comment: @Pavel вариант Леонида вроде тоже должен сработать `this.array = [...initArray]`. Потому что происходит сразу и объявление и инициализация

Comment: @Pavel , а что в C++ можно задавать значение ячейке массива до его объявления?

Comment: @Leonid нет,я другое имел в виду,я не знал что в js поля класса задаются в конструкторе.

Comment: @Pavel, ясно)) , класс действительно в JS суррогатная синтаксическая конструкция. Есть некоторые особенности))

Comment: @Leonid  я вот что-то слышал про typescript и другие аналоги,я так понял там синтаксис полегче?Или в чем основная разница?

Comment: @Pavel вроде то же самое просто с указанием типов данных. Основные конструкции те же. Но точно я не знаю)) DART вроде более похож на С языки, его можно и в JS конвертировать. Python насколько я пока понял от JS мало отличается, еще большей расхлябанностью только))

Comment: @Pavel typescript - типизированный язык. И в нём слегка проще будет, если привыкли к классам. Потому что таких сюрпризов будет меньше, чем в чистом JS (например свойства можно объявлять так, как все привыкли)) до конструктора в отдельном блоке). Но т.к. это всё равно своего рода надстройка над JS, сюрпризы всё же будут))  Можете посмотреть. Может понравится

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо,посмотрю)